# Controlling external applications through custom GUI

Tags: vb.net, blend

I am working on creating a custom interface through Microsoft Blend. I have two applications that I would like to control through my interface (open program, perform activities in the program using the programs defined methods, save program files, quit). One of the programs contains a lot of information on vb.Net automation. The other program only has two interfaces in it's interop dll and I can't seem to work with either of them.

The programs are Calypso and PCDMIS. Calypso has a CalypsoInterface.dll with a Calypso interface inside that I am trying to interact with. PCDMIS has a PCDLRN.dll with an Application interface that I am working with.

For Calypso, I try this and it fails (cannot create ActiveX component):

```
Dim CALApp as New CalypsoInterface.Calypso
CALApp = CreateObject("CalypsoInterface.Calypso")
```

For PCDMIS, this works just fine:

```
Dim PCDApp as New PCDLRN.Application
PCDApp = CreateObject("PCDLRN.Application")
```

Does anybody have any solid resources on this type of control? I'm not even sure where to look. Also, if this question gets flagged/closed because it is not a direct question, does anybody know which stack exchange site I can ask things like this on?

Comment: I would suggest asking one question at a time.  For instance, if you have a question about why the VB.NET automation api for the one application doesn't work, then ask a question about that, with the code that you've tried and an explanation of how it's failing with any error messages, if applicable.  Same goes for the one with the interop dll.  If no API is provided for the functions you need, your only resort may be to look into sending window messages to control it like a UI macro.

Comment: Both of the applications have an interop dll. For the one that I am having a hard time with, I am accessing a file called CalypsoInterface.dll. Inside this .dll there is an interface called Calypso. I am trying to write the following code:

Dim CALApp as New CalypsoInterface.Calypso
CALApp = CreateObject("CalypsoInterface.Calypso")

I am receiving issues such as "Cannot create ActiveX component"
I have gone ahead and registered the .dll using regsvr32 to no avail.

Would sending window messages allow me to access any feature that I could normally just click on?

Comment: @JacobCheverie Also, please don't put code in the comments, please put them in the OP so everyone can see it as it can get lost in this section.

Comment: Are you referencing the library at design-time as a COM reference in your project, or are you just loading it late-bound at runtime using `CreateObject`?  Seems like you are doing both, based on the code you posted, which is strange.  Do both lines cause that error, or just one of them?

Comment: What I'm getting at is that, if you are declaring the variable `As New Whatever`, then later setting the variable to `CreateObject("Whatever")` is redundant.

Comment: @StevenDoggart I am referencing as a COM reference in Visual Studio. Only CreateObject() gives the error. I agree that it is redundant. In the documentation for the non-Calypso program, that is the way that they do it, as you can see by my post edit. Admittedly redundant, it works alright and the program opens. Am I looking at the wrong library or something?

Comment: I would remove the `CreateObject` from both places, unless you plan to remove the COM reference and late-bind it.  Simply creating the COM object won't necessarily display the application--it all depends on how they wrote it.  You may need to call some method like `CALApp.Show` to get it to display the application.

Comment: @StevenDoggart I will take a look at some other methods when I get back to work tomorrow. Thank you for your feedback.